# Ruby On Rails : Difference between Gem & Plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

What is the difference between Gem & Plugin?

Comment: Please refere question showing [Defference Between Gem and Pluggin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521224/difference-between-plugins-and-ruby-gems).
Please search questions and then ask

Answer (score 2):

According to [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html) there are two types of (Rails) plugins:

- specific to your application: *vendored plugin*
- useful across applications: *gemified plugin* (or *gem*)

So, a *gem* is a plugin that is installed onto a system and is available in all (Ruby) applications. For example *Ruby on Rails* is a set of *gems*. And a (regular or vendored) *plugin* is directly installed into an application and only available locally.

Comment: Thanks bro.. Simple and Clear